# Why does codebehind value differ from console value?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a dynamic panel I build in codebehind, and add the attribute "data-use" and set it to "false".

On the running page, I have a javascript function that runs, and sets that panels "data-use" attribute to "true".

Now, when I debug the codebehind and step through the code, when I look at the panel in the immediate window with

```
?pnlName.Attributes("data-use")
```

I get a return value of false, but while the page is paused, and I bring up the web console (in Chrome Dev Tools) and use jQuery to get the attribute value

```
$("#panelid").attr("data-use");
```

it returns a true value...

Now I will admit that I'm very new to VB.net (new job) but a) why are these 2 values different, and b) how can I get the codebehind to see this value as true?

Comment: is that attribute changed by javascript?

Comment: Yes - there is a javascript function that runs on certain page events that cause this attribute to change.

Comment: you have to use a request to send that change to the server.

Comment: Is this WebForms?  Please do some studying on the page life-cycle and what a Post-back is.

Comment: Is that really the only option?  That seems like complete overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT ALL attributes are posted as postback event occurs in ASP.Net. You may call it a limitation. It could be solved by adding a hidden field to your  panel dynamically , setting the value to false and then changing the value of the hidden field in javascript, Then on the postback you will get the changed value of the hidden field in the postback. Try it.